# C++ - Instantiating derived class and using base class's constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a base class with a constructor that requires one parameter (string).  Then I have a derived class which also has its' own constructor.  I want to instantiate the derived class and be able to set the parameter of the base class's constructor as well.

```
class BaseClass {
    public:
        BaseClass (string a);
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
        DerivedClass (string b);
};

int main() {
    DerivedClass abc ("Hello");
}
```

I'm not sure how to set the base class constructor's parameter when calling the derived class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two possibilities - inline:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass (string b) : BaseClass(b) {}
};
```

or out of line:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass (string b);
};

/* ... */
DerivedClass::DerivedClass(string b) : BaseClass(b)
{}
```

---

more examples:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass(int a, string b, string c);

private:
    int x;
};

DerivedClass::DerivedClass(int a, string b, string c) : BaseClass(b + c), x(a)
{}
```

---

on initializer lists:

```
class MyType {
public:
    MyType(int val) { myVal = val; }    // needs int
private:
    int myVal;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    DerivedClass(int a, string b) : BaseClass(b)
    {  x = a;  }   // error, this tries to assign 'a' to default-constructed 'x'
                   // but MyType doesn't have default constructor

    DerivedClass(int a, string b) : BaseClass(b), x(a)
    {}             // this is the way to do it
private:
    MyType x;
};
```

Comment: What if I want to set the base constructor's parameter value to something different than the derived class's parameter?

Comment: @yeenow123 then use `DerivedClass::DerivedClass(string b) : BaseClass("cat")`

Comment: Of course you can. The context in the base class initializer is the same as inside the constructor body (except the members are not yet initialized, so you can't use them)

Comment: @Wug I mean when creating an instance in the main() for example.  I wouldn't want to hardcode the base class's parameter value.

Comment: Can you really think of no way to do it?  Edit - I'll give you a hint. it involves commas.

Comment: @yeenow123 What would you want to set the `Base` constructor parameter to?

Comment: Then you need `Derived::Derived(string a, string b) : Base(a) { something with b }`.

Comment: In the int main() when creating the instance..

DerivedClass abc ("Hello") ("Goodbye");

"Hello" would be the DerivedClass's parameter and "Goodbye" the BaseClass's parameter.  Is that clear?

Comment: @yeenow123 No, thats not possible. The way you pass values to your base class is entirely in the implementation of derived class - not in the hands of the derived class user

Comment: @Fiktik Ah ok, that's what I wanted to know.  Looks like I'll have to go about it another way.  Thanks!
Quick question, what is the x(a) doing in your last example?

Comment: @yeenow123 the `x(a)` thing is called initializer list - you can initialize your members the same way you pass values to the base class. In here it is the same as saying `x = a` in constructor body, because `x` is int. But if `x` was an object that needs an integer in its constructor, then the only way how to initialize such a member would be with the initializer list. I will add another example.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is construct a derived class instance from a single parameter that you pass to the base class constructor, you can to this:

C++03 (I have added explicit, and pass by const reference):

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
        explicit DerivedClass (const std::string& b) : BaseClass(b) {}
};
```

C++11 (gets all the base class constructors):

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    using BaseClass::BaseClass;
};
```

If you want to call different `DerivedClass` constructors and call the `BaseClass` constructor to some other value, you can do it too:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
        explicit DerivedClass () : BaseClass("Hello, World!") {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 DerivedClass::DerivedClass(string b)
     : BaseClass(b)
 {
 }
```

just pass the parameter direct to the base class constructor